# Add the actual characters '\n' to a string in python?

Tags: python, line-breaks

I'm writing a short program to go through a directory and write create table and load from csv statements for a bunch of csvs and get them all into mySQL. I'm sure there's an easier way to do this, but I thought it would be fun to make it myself.

This is one of the lines I have in python to build the load csv statement, where l_d is a variable I'm storing it in, f is the file path, and n is the table name:

```
 l_d = "LOAD DATA INFILE " + "'" + f + "'" + "\nINTO TABLE " + n + "\nFIELDS TERMINATED BY ','\nENCLOSED BY '" + '"' +"'" + "\nLINES TERMINATED BY" +"\'\n\'" + "\nIGNORE 1 ROWS;"
```

The statement I want in SQL is:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY'\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

but what I get is always

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY'
'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

because it thinks my \n is supposed to be a line break and not the actual characters.

How can I get the actual characters to show up here?

Also, I know my whole string concatenation in the original statement is kinda gross (I'm pretty new to this), so any general tips on how to improve that would also be much appreciated :)

Comment: either `r'\n'` (make the string raw so all characters are interpreted as is) or `'\\n'` (escape the backslash so it is interpreted as a literal backslash); for better/faster string formatting you can use [`f strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly

Comment: @Matiiss that's right, but in some cases we need escape characters and writing a name of a folder starting with the letter n for example  So I think getting used to use the backspace escape character would be better.

Comment: @mohamedyahya in the specific case of paths raw strings can be used way more easily than escaping backslashes, you need to add one letter r instead of double the backslashes, yes, in most cases there is no need for a raw string but I just provided the two ways of doing it, the raw and escaping way (which you have seemingly missed in my comment)

Comment: @Matiiss yeah, I agree with you, but it was just an advice which may help, no offense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to escape the backspace add another one before it:

```
\\n
```

gets \n

so your code will be:

```
 l_d = "LOAD DATA INFILE " + "'" + f + "'" + "\nINTO TABLE " + n + 
 "\nFIELDS TERMINATED BY ','\nENCLOSED BY '" + '"' +"'" + "\nLINES 
 TERMINATED BY" +"\'\\n\'" + "\nIGNORE 1 ROWS;"
```

Answer (score 0):

print("hello\ \n")
#this print a original "\n"